# Доступ к полю класса java

Tags: java, классы, field

Прошу помочь и по возможности дать разъяснения, почему не могу получить доступ к полю name у объекта.
Ведь в классе поле имеет Public и по идее доступ к нему должен быть.....
Засада в этой части блока, где я должен вывести на экран в каждой новой строке имена объектов в Set.
к объеку не привязыввется поле name

```
Iterator<Object> itr = setOfCats.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            Object obj_forPrint = itr.next();
            System.out.println(obj_forPrint.name);
        }
```

Весь код

```
public class Solution {

    public static class Cat2
    {
        public String name;

        Cat2 (String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void createCats(Set<Object> setOfObjects)
    {
        Cat2 cat1 = new Cat2("Барсик");
        Cat2 cat2 = new Cat2("Барсик1");
        Cat2 cat3 = new Cat2("Барсик2");

        setOfObjects.add(cat1);
        setOfObjects.add(cat2);
        setOfObjects.add(cat3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<Object> setOfCats = new HashSet<>();
        createCats(setOfCats);
        for (Object obj : setOfCats)
        {
            setOfCats.remove(obj);
            break;
        }
        Iterator<Object> itr = setOfCats.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            Object obj_forPrint = itr.next();
            System.out.println(obj_forPrint.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у `Object` нет поля `name`. Либо приводите объект к типу `Cat2`, либо храните объекты класса `Cat2`, а не `Object`

Comment: Спасибо все заработало..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент добавления в колекцию, которая обобщенная типом Object вы передаете туда ссылку другого типа  а именно Cat2 (Java разрешает это делать, так как это основной механизм для обеспечения полиморфизма и собственно Object является самым верхним в иерархии наследования класом).В вашем случаи вы передаете в колекцию объект Cat2 и в качестве указателя используете тип Object который и будет указывать на ваш объект Cat2 в куче. Так вот в момент обращения к определенному объекту который был добавлен в колекцию таким образом, компилятору не интересен объект (В нашем случаи это Cat2) на который указывает ссылка (типа Object) он смотрит лиш на её тип (Object), таким образом он думает что раз у вас ссылка имеет тип Object то и в куче у вас тоже объект Object. Исходя из этого в зависимотри от того какой тип ссылки вы используете, такие методы и переменные уровня экземпляра вам будут доступны.

Проще говоря ваш объект с типом ссылки Cat2 включает в себя два класа тоесть это сам клас Cat2 и собственно Object. Таким образом тип ссылки это будто пульт от определенного класа из которого состоит объект, какой тип ссылки такими и будут доступные переменные и методы для использывания.

Ну например:

```
    Object obj = new Cat2;
    obj.getCatName();// это не сработает так как компилятор смотрит лиш на тип ссылки.
```

Тоесть если вы хотите получить полный функционал подкласа Cat2 посредством присвоения его ссылке типа Object сделайте приведение типов.

```
   Object obj = new Cat2();
   Cat2 cat = (Cat2) obj;
   cat.getCatName(); // таким образом все прекрасно работает
```

При этом это будет все тот же объект Cat2 который вы изначально например добавили в колекцию так как ссылка по прежнему будет указывать на ваш объект в куче.
Надеюсь мой ответ был полезен.

Answer (score 2):

Замените все `<Object>` на `<Cat2>`.